# How to collect all values of specific product into one cell?

Tags: excel-2007

hi i want all values of product A to be collected in a cell G7
[image]

Comment: Is VBA solution acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

Without use of VBA the only solution is to use helper column and combine each row individually if it matches desired criteria. For example if you would create new column with header "A" in column C with the following formula (starting from cell C2):

```
 =IF(A2=C$1;C1&B2;C1)
```

In cell C14 you would get `AQWERTYUIO` - it starts with an "A" which was your header name. Now you can easily get your result from last row of the data or looking on longest value. To get longest string from column C you can use:

```
=INDEX(C2:C14,MATCH(MAX(LEN(C2:C14)),LEN(C2:C14)),0)
```

it's an array formula so you should use shift+enter while entering it. To remove first A just do something like this (assuming that result of above formula is in cell G7):

```
=RIGHT(G7,LEN(G7)-1)
```

Hope that helps.